# Database Design | PHP-Mysql | JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, report

I am developing an application using F3   in which report generation is a sub-app.
Now i have the reports in the form of json data which will be large.

Problem is that, JSON data is in multiple levels and difficult to define schema for it.

Now, any suggestion on how i should store the JSON,   as file? or in mysql database as blob or text?

Note: I would JSON data only to generate report (PDF, Excel etc) . I never modify it.

Thank you,
Sash.

Comment: You store it as you want it.. Its 100% your personal choice..

Comment: JSON usually has a set format/structure. Most people use databases but they don't store the JSON as text, they will extract the values from the JSON and store them in relevant tables/fields.

Comment: @Svetlio  Hmm. I am concerned about performance here. Any idea how big applications store data which is used for report generation?

Comment: @mATTHEW    The JSON is like huge with many sub levels. so i will need to create many tables and joins (MANY),  so i'm thinking, when i generate a report i can simply get the json file and generate report, why parse the whole JSON to store to database and again while generating report why query multiple tables with each field having about 2000 long characters ?

Comment: Soo many dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564024/storing-data-in-mysql-as-json, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978263/php-mysql-storing-array-data-as-json-bad-practice, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990762/how-to-store-json-string-in-mysql-db, ...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem  Hello, they this is not a duplicate, i want to know if creating Mysql schema for JSON is better or simply storing JSON file is better (not to database)   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you're going to be using that JSON data as read-only material, to build PDF's then it sort of depends on a number of things:

- How many JSON formatted objects are we talking about? Storing them stringified isn't that much of a problem (as the question I marked as duplicate states). Of course, if we're talking about thousands of JSON strings, you'll need to index that table (those tables) and that requires either a unique id that's unrelated to the actual data, or parsing the string, and using some properties you could use to query.
- You say the JSON-objects are fairly large (because you're talking about TEXT/BLOB fields) which can hold up to 65k characters... Are you sure you're going to be using even half that amount of chars, 20% of the time?? It does feel like overkill to me, to be honest
- How variable is the JSON's structure? does one object consist of a simple JS-style object literal while the other one is a 7-level-deep nested object? If all objects share a certain structure, you're probably going to be better of building a schema.
- I don't know if you're comfortable with it, or it's an option in your case, but since you're not going to be writing to that table too often, and it's al JSON formatted, why not look into another DB system? It's been a while, but I have worked with [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) which could be useful to you.

Recap: If you only have, say, ~10 JSON objects: just store them in a simple table as VARCHARS (or TEXT), add an id field if needs must. If you can, a simple file will do, too, of course. No need to connect to a MySQL server, no need for all that overhead just `file_get_contents('JSON_DATA1.json');` can do the trick. Of course, take safety precautions where needed.
If you have tons of objects, build a MySQL schema... unless the objects have *truly* no similarities as far as format goes (no similar properties @ the same level)
Do take a look at alternatives like mongoDB and, perhaps, other NoSQL DB's. They might be of use to you. Mongo, for example, stores its data in JSON-style documents and is quite easy to work with because of it's JavaScript-like interface.